# SQL Server Contains Exact Phrase with Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to query exact phrase with clause using `CONTAINS` in SQL Server?

```
Select * 
from mytable 
where contains(mycolumn,' "257(1)(e)" ')
```

Result get and operator not exact phrase:

Note:

`Like` query works fine:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where mycolumn like '%257(1)(e)%'
```

But I can't use `Like` because of performance issues.

I tried to use Near and ~ but still ?

Answer (score 1):

CHARINDEX is another option

```
select * from mytable where charindex('"257(1)(e)"', mycolumn)=1
```

But all of these options, such as LIKE, PATINDEX are slower than [FULL TEXT INDEXING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). Searching on a fully indexed field is several orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: `CONTAINS` is a full text index query.

Comment: ya basically am creating search engine for my website and i need the full indexing search because of BIG TEXT Data